# Permission denied when using make install

Tags: software-installation

when I invoke the command make install ,it shows another error.

```
test -z "/usr/local/include/libxml2/libxml" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/include/libxml2/libxml"
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/include/libxml2’: Permission denied
make[4]: *** [install-xmlincHEADERS] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/madhuv/y/libxml2-2.9.2/include/libxml'
make[3]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/madhuv/y/libxml2-2.9.2/include/libxml'
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/madhuv/y/libxml2-2.9.2/include'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/madhuv/y/libxml2-2.9.2'
make: *** [install] Error 2.
```

please help me.

Comment: As this is tagged "software-installation": a vast amount of programs can (and in general should) be installed via Softwarecenter or `apt-get`. Next would be installing a .deb file. The `make install` way of doing things is for rather advanced users, and even then I frankly do not remember when I had to do that for the last time... Are you a developer? Then simply run `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev`.

Answer (score 4):

@NewUSer's solution is absolutely correct, but I have to make another proposal:

Not always the command `sudo make uninstall` is supported. For this reason, I recommend the use of `sudo checkinstall` instead of `sudo make install`:

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
```

With this program a DEB package is created which can be easily removed with the package management again.

Instead of

```
sudo make install
```

use

```
sudo checkinstall
```

Comment: I'll have to remember this one!

Answer (score 3):

Here is your problem

> /bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/include/libxml2’:
>   Permission denied

It's probably that you are not using `sudo`

You should run make install using sudo

so run the command again

```
sudo make install
```

Read answer here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20953/difference-between-make-install-and-sudo-make-install to know why you should use `sudo` with `make install`