# How do I install pybel such that my python environment recognizes it?

Tags: python, cmake, openbabel

On [Chemistry Stack Exchange](http://goo.gl/GTRGSE) I asked a question regarding Open Babel & Python being used together.

The problem is that the answer I was provided (by Geoff Hutchinson) requires Python to be able to import the module Pybel.

I have installed Open Babel on this PC via two ways, APT and source. I then deleted my APT installation after I realized pybel wasn't available for Python use and I decided to install from source with Python bindings.

To do so I followed [this guide](http://openbabel.org/docs/dev/Installation/install.html) with the final command being customized to (running from `~/build`)

```
cmake ../openbabel-2.3.2 -DBUILD_GUI=ON -DPYTHON_BINDINGS=ON
```

which gave the output:

```
-- Using included inchi library.
-- Found wxWidgets: TRUE  
-- Cairo found. PNG output will be supported.
-- Attempting to build the GUI
--    wxWidgets found => GUI will be built
CMake Warning (dev) at test/CMakeLists.txt:171 (include):
  Syntax Warning in cmake code at

    /home/fusion809/Downloads/openbabel-2.3.2/cmake/modules/UsePythonTest.cmake:54:14

  Argument not separated from preceding token by whitespace.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at test/CMakeLists.txt:171 (include):
  Syntax Warning in cmake code at

    /home/fusion809/Downloads/openbabel-2.3.2/cmake/modules/UsePythonTest.cmake:54:31

  Argument not separated from preceding token by whitespace.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at test/CMakeLists.txt:171 (include):
  Syntax Warning in cmake code at

    /home/fusion809/Downloads/openbabel-2.3.2/cmake/modules/UsePythonTest.cmake:57:25

  Argument not separated from preceding token by whitespace.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at test/CMakeLists.txt:171 (include):
  Syntax Warning in cmake code at

    /home/fusion809/Downloads/openbabel-2.3.2/cmake/modules/UsePythonTest.cmake:57:39

  Argument not separated from preceding token by whitespace.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Python bindings will be compiled
-- Could NOT find Ruby (missing:  RUBY_INCLUDE_DIR RUBY_LIBRARY RUBY_CONFIG_INCLUDE_DIR) (found version "2.1.0")
-- Ruby library files NOT found. Ruby bindings will NOT be compiled.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/fusion809/build
```

I should mention, however, that the first time I compiled Open Babel I forgot to add the `-DBUILD_GUI` & `-DPYTHON_BINDINGS` commands to the cmake line, so I had to run this new cmake command after I had initially compiled the software. Does this make any difference? Should I remove Open Babel and re-compile? If so do I have to delete some files in my `/usr/` directory to (if so please mention them as I don't know which ones)? If relevant I am on 32 bit 15.04.

## EDIT

I deleted my build directory's contents & started again and after the cmake command I ran:

```
make
sudo make install
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib:$PYTHONPATH
```

At the end of the output I received were these two lines:

```
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/openbabel.py
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/pybel.py
```

In a Python terminal I ran `import openbabel` and `import pybel` and it gave the output: `ImportError: No module named ...` where `...` is openbabel or pybel, depending on which of the commands were executed, so I suspect it's a problem on my Python installation's end.

Comment: Try a `sudo make uninstall` before a `sudo make install`. And start a `make clean` before a `make`

Comment: Tried & failed. `sudo make uninstall` gave the error: `make: *** No rule to make target 'uninstall'. Stop.`

Comment: That's maybe a problem. I have an idea. Install `checkinstall` with `sudo apt-get install checkinstall` and start the installation again with `sudo checkinstall` and not with `sudo make install`. Checkinstall installs a deb package and overwrites your previous installation. Then open the package manager and remove the installed package. Then start the compilation again and use in future `checkinstall` and not `make install`. Read [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/624018/367165) for an explanation for `checkinstall`.

Comment: do I replace `make` (by itself) with checkinstall?

Comment: no, not `make` only a `make install`: `sudo make install` is now `sudo checkinstall`

Comment: Tried & failed again, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without `python-openbabel`:

```
% python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr  2 2015, 15:33:21) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import openbabel
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named openbabel
>>>

% python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr  2 2015, 15:33:21) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pybel
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pybel
>>>
```

Install `python-openbabel`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-openbabel
```

Check:

```
% python  
Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr  2 2015, 15:33:21) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import openbabel
>>>

% python                     
Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr  2 2015, 15:33:21) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pybel
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and figured out that I was using a python distribution (Anaconda) other than the original (the one provided by Ubuntu). Below is a potential workaround (if this is the case).

After installing python-openbabel using apt-get, check it with the system-provided python (in my case `/usr/bin/python`). You should be able to import openbabel:

```
% /usr/bin/python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import openbabel
>>>
```

I tried to use `easy_install` provided by Anaconda to install openbabel & pybel but it was not successful. Then I copied the `*openbabel*` and `*pybel*` files in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` to a folder that `PYTHONPATH` sees and it worked fine. I would appreciate if anyone has a nicer (cleaner) way to make Anaconda use  of the package installed for system-provided python.

(I wanted to comment to the answer but due to the lack of reputation I couldnt)